# How do I check if the homescreen is showing on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, jailbreak, springboard

I want to be able to call `SBUIController's` `activateApplicationAnimated:` on an app from my MobileSubstrate dylib. However, that call won't work if the iPhone/iPod is at the lockscreen (or if an app is already open). How do I test to see if the homescreen is showing?

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the locked status, at least, using `-[SBAwayController isLocked]` (present on 4.3, no other versions checked). I can't find any interesting-looking methods in the headers for checking whether the homescreen is obscured by an application.

You could attempt to track application launch and termination, but it might just be better to look into using libactivator for activating your Tweak. This will give the user the ability to configure what triggers it, AND the ability to restrict action to the homescreen only.

Check it out at [its page](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Libactivator) on the iPhone Development Wiki!

Comment: Actually There's a method that's called when the lockscreen finishes animating out, so I hooked that and just activated the app when that was done.